# Pagination for Custom Taxonomy Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, pagination

I'm having an issue getting my custom taxonomy page to paginate correctly. I looked through other examples posted on this forum, but I could not get my second page to not return a 404 error page.  Here are my details

- **Custom Tax:** Study_Tags
- **Example Terms:** Community, Economy, Crime...
- **Custom Taxonomy Page:** taxonomy-study_tags.php
- **Posts Per Page:** 5 *(set in Reading Settings, global for all pages/posts on site)*

I am using a Custom Post Type "Study" with the custom taxonomy "Study Tags", which is why i feel I need to use the "query_posts()" function.

I only want to show parent pages in the results, as each "Study" CPT can have children page with study details, presentations... etc.

My information to setup the query

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, 
    array(
            'post_type'=> 'study',
            'post_parent' => '0',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            ));
            query_posts($args);

?>
```

$wp_query->query_vars passes for example "[study_tags] => community" when var_dump() is used, so I know it is transmitting the correct term to the custom tax page.

Any ideas how to get a second page of results?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **never** use `query_posts`: when you need to change the main query, is a lot better use the `pre_get_posts` hook: your site users will thank you, once performance will increase.

If the custom taxonomy `study_tags` is used only for `study` CPT the only reason to change default query is to set post parent to `0`.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','set_study_parent');

function set_study_parent( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && is_main_query() && is_tax('study_tags') ) {
    $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
  }
}
```

Then in your `taxonomy-study_tags.php` template, you can just use the loop. Pagination will work without doing anything else.

Comment: +1. Never EVER EVER EVER use `query_posts()`. It's amazing how easily pagination issues disappear when replacing `query_posts()` with a proper `pre_get_posts` filter.